# Updating a contact list from another class when new contact is added from Modal Window--WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know ways to do this, but I am trying to find out what the "proper" way to do this using MVVM and/or WPF guidelines.

So basically here is my situation:

- I have a Window(Customers) that has a customer list and then a listbox showing the contacts for that customer.
- I have a button called "Add Contacts" which opens up a new Window(Contacts) as a modal where the users can enter a new contact and add it to the DataBase.
- I pass in the Customer_ID to the constructor when I create the new Contacts Window from the Customers Window.
- When they are done adding in the new Contact information, they close the Contacts window and are still in the Customers Window.

What I want to know is, once they press the "Submit Contact" button and it saves the new contact to the database, what is the "proper" way to get that new contact added in the Contact Window to the ObservableCollection of contacts in the Customers Window (without declaring a global public variable---obviously I already know that).

I am using MVVM where the View Model contains the public/private properties and collections which are bound to the various controls on the Window itself, and the Code behind instantiates an instance of the ViewModel.

UPDATE SOLVED: I want to smack myself in the face for this one.  Basically I just created a public delegate in the Child Window of type Contact and then subscribed to it in the Parent Window and then added that Contact passed via the delegate to the list of contacts

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking this...

Either the window should provide a new instance via a method call after success is reported, or the individual properties should be set as dependency properties and create a new instance from those properties. Either way take and add a new instance copy into the VM's observable collection.

No need to roundtrip back to the database to get either the new value or a whole list of objects.